# Headset not found on Xperia L

Tags: bluetooth, sony-xperia, headset

I've bought Sony [MBH20](http://www.sonymobile.com/gb/products/accessories/mono-bluetooth-headset-mbh20/) headset and Bluetooth transmitter ASUS BT400 to use it both for skype calls and with my Xperia L.

When I unpacked the headset I've succesfully paired with my Xperia.

When I tried to pair it with PC i removed it from list of bluetooth devices in the Xperia and paired it with PC (Win7, 64 bit).

From that moment I cannot detect the headset with my Xperia. It displays other bluetooth devices but not the headset. I tried turning the headset off and on, I tried to remove the hadset from devices in the PC and I tried to clear cache and AppData of SmartConnect app.

In all cases I can find, add and use hte headset with the PC but Xperia stll resist to detect it.

Is it caused by:

- Deleting the headset from Xperia's list of (paired) devices?
- Pairing with the PC resuilting in switching the headset's BT to be visible only for the PC?

How can I force the headset to connect to available host (PC or Cell phone), if both are active, connect to the last paired?

Comment: @DanHulme Yes, it needed to be put into "discovery mode". There's only one button on the headset. And I've also found - by try-observe technique - that short click can accept the call, longer click acts as a on/off switch and even longer click enforces "discovery mode"... If you happen to know where to migrate this question, do it, please. Even if the proper "site" is oblivion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After removing the pairing from the phone, the phone won't be able to see the headset in its normal mode any more. To connect to it again, you need to pair the phone with the headset again. To make the headset visible again, you need to put it into a special "pairing mode" which makes it visible to all devices for a short time.

The way of doing this varies from one headset to another, but typically you might hold down the power button for a longer time, until the light on the headset blinks (if there is one). On headsets with a volume control, you might need to hold one of the volume buttons before pressing the power button. (I've seen that on a Jabra headset.) With the headset in its pairing mode, search for devices from your phone and you should be able to see it and pair with it. After that, the phone will be able to connect to it automatically, like before you deleted the pairing.

It's very unusual for peripherals to only be able to hold one pairing at a time, so once your headset is paired with both the PC and the phone, you should be able to connect to either. You can only connect to one at a time, though. To learn more about [how Bluetooth pairing works and pairing with multiple devices](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/140662/12442), you might like to read my related answer.